# Find links into a text using regex

Tags: regex

There are already several post about finding link into a text but none of them fully work in my case.
This one is the closer I got:

```
    $reg_exUrl = "#(https?|ftp)://\S+[^\s.,>)\];'\"!?]#";   
    preg_match_all( $reg_exUrl, $content, $result );
```

This almost works for all case except for the following content:

```
$content = '<p><br></p><p>https://www.google.com <br></p><p>http://localhost/index.php?view=model&nbsp;<br></p><p><br></p><p>http://localhost/index.php?view=scheduler/ <br></p><p><br></p><p>http://localhost/index.php?view=module<br></p><p><br></p><p><br></p>';
```

If the link is not followed by a space then the preg_match_all takes the HTML following the link as part of the link

How do I modify the regex so that it stops when there is an HTML tag?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the below regex to find the links in the above mentioned string,

```
(https?|ftp)://.*?(?=&nbsp|\s|<|>)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/dT6dN8/5)